# creating quiz jquery, function load options store quiz

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, jquery

code: http://jsfiddle.net/HB8h9/7/

```
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">

        <label for="tfq" title="Enter a true or false question">
            Enter a Multiple Choice Question
        </label> <br />

        <textarea name="tfq" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
        <p>Mark the correct answer</p>
        <input type="radio" name="multians" value="A">A)</input>
        <input name="Avalue" type="text">
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="multians" value="B">B)</input>
        <input name="Bvalue" type="text">
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="multians" value="C">C)</input>
        <input name="Cvalue" type="text">
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="multians" value="D">D)</input>
        <input name="Dvalue" type="text">
        <br>
```

---

//different file below used as main page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#second li ").click(function() {
        $("#content").load("file_above.html .tabs");
    });
});
```

trying to create a quiz using div elements from different file containing select option tags.  Need to create a function which will load all the "appropriate div tags" according to the selected option and display the dropdown options again after each option has been selected.  I'm not sure when to implement submit button either after each question type is loaded or somewhere between 5 - 10 questions.  the submit button will "store" the questions selected into a quiz which will later be used for another user to answer.

I hope this makes sense, I'm not too familiar with jquery and any help would be highly appreciated.

Any other techniques which would be better suited are also welcomed.
thanks.

Comment: what is your problem here? how to store quiz? how to load an show?

Comment: according to my understanding you need to load the **divs** with respect to the **options** selected right?

Comment: if you got your OP, don't forget to accept.

Answer (score 0):

You must set an id to select element and hadle onChange event over this.
Somehting like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectionId').onChange(function(){
        /*load new options into select element*/
        $(this).append('option data-tab="tab-6">New option text</option>');
        /*displaying desired div. Using HTML5 data attributes as in the fiddle*/
        var selected=$(this).attr('data-tab');
        if (selected==='tab-1'){
            /*load or display tab-1 class div*/
        }else...
    });
});
```

You can have various html files with only the corresponding tab to load or in the same file you are defined the select element you can have the tab class divs with visibility attribute set to 'none' and show the targeted div after user selects an option.

Personally, I preferred the last one option.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this fixes your problem

http://jsfiddle.net/r9sv8/

Use the `.change()` to listen to the options selected and display the `div` respect to it.

```
$('.tabs').change(function(){
        $('.tabQues').hide('500');       // Hides all the divs
        var changeVal = $(this).val();   //Takes the value of the <option>
        if(changeVal=="selectOne"){
            $('.'+changeVal).show('500');   //show the div you want
        }else if(changeVal=="multiple"){
            $('.'+changeVal).show('500');
        }else if(changeVal=="trueFalse"){
            $('.'+changeVal).show('500');
        }else if(changeVal=="short"){
            $('.'+changeVal).show('500');
        }else if(changeVal=="program"){
            $('.'+changeVal).show('500');
        }else{
            $('.tabQues').hide();
        }
```